# How to Configure JS with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
$(function(){

$("form").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var password = $('#inputPassword').val();
    var doublep = $('#checkPassword').val();

    $.post("updatepassword.php",
    {
        password: password,
        doublep: doublep
    },

    function(data)
    {
        if(data.result == 'changed') {
             $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Success!</strong> Your password was successfully changed.</div>').fadeIn(1000);
        } else if (data.result == 'error'){
            $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Error!</strong> Could not update your password. Please contact an admin.</div>').fadeIn(1000);
        } else if (data.result == 'dontmatch'){
            $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Error!</strong> The passwords you entered didnt match! Please try again.</div>').fadeIn(1000);
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

});

Here is a Java Script code that takes 2 input values and goes to the PHP, in the updatepassword.php how can I take those 2 values to my PHP codes and give the data.result?

p.s: I don't get credits for the java script code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're posting to that page, access like this

```
$val1 = $_POST['val1'];
$val2 = $_POST['val2'];
```

and if you're using get method,

```
$val1 = $_GET['val1'];
$val2 = $_GET['val2'];
```

and use `$val1` and `$val2` and do your stuff, at the end, just do `echo` that you want to send back

```
//let's say $stuff is your final data.
$stuff = array("Return this stuff back");
echo json_encode($stuff);
```

read more about [**`$_POST`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), [**`$_GET`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), [**`Variables`**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) and [**`json_encode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: So when I do the array and echo json_encode, the java script will get the return and will do the process?

Comment: when you'll `echo`, you'll get stuff inside your `javascript` code